# Android ViewPager with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an App using ViewPager which has 3 tabs.  I need each tab to contain a navigation stack of fragments e.g. I have a list on the first fragment which will then display a detail fragment based on clicking an item.  What is the best way to design this?  At the moment, I have one MainActivity which replaces the Fragments within each tab but as I'm adding more fragments within each tab, the MainActivity will just become huge.  Can I handle all of this within the fragments themselves?

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpagertabstrip-fragments-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [tabhost with backstack](https://github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy). This makes use of a `TabHost`, and is not the same as using a `ViewPager` with tabs. But that solution on Github is a very good one.

Also, this will not make your `MainActivity` "huge", because all the `Fragment`s can be defined as separate classes in their own class files. `Fragment`s are supposed to represent more *modular* UI blocks.

Comment: What I mean with the MainActivity is that each OnFragmentInteractionListener will have to be implemented and then the code to replace the fragment inserted into each implementation.

Comment: if you take a look at the link i have posted, it has an elegant solution of handling fragments in tabs with a backstack, and the code does not make use of interfaces to communicate between activity and fragments